# Tooltip in a modal with backbone.marionette and twitter bootstrap

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, modal-dialog, marionette

I have a button in a backbone.marionette app which opens a modal and I'd like to have tooltips in this modal.

The view which displays the modal in the modal region:

```
class MyApp.Views.UserInfos extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView

    template: 'backbone/templates/user_infos'

    events:
        'click button': 'send_invitation'

    send_invitation: () ->
        invitation = new MyApp.Models.Invitation({username: @model.get('name')})
        modal_view = new MyApp.Views.InvitationSettings({model: invitation})
        App.modal.show(modal_view)
        $("#modal").modal('show')
```

The modal view in which I want tooltips:

```
class MyApp.Views.InvitationSettings extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView

    template: 'backbone/templates/invitation_settings'

    onShow: () ->
        $(".icon-question-sign").tooltip()
```

I initialize the tooltips when the region is shown and it doesn't work. Worse, when I hover the zone where the tooltip might be the modal window closes but the backdrop doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the onRender callback.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/gag5a/

```
var ToolView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:"#tool-template",
    tagName: "span",
    onRender: function() {
        this.$el.find('a').tooltip();
    }
});
```

Comment: It works with the onShow callback too. It was my selector that was bad... Thanks!

Comment: No worries.  Just keep in mind that onShow is triggered by the region.  If you re-render the view and add new elements that require tooltips you will want to use onRender.